# UTC Time is wrong in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using below code to get GMT(India Time) time but the code shows wrong value. I tried both UTC and GMT in timezone.

```
val f = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z")
println("Hello World"+f)
f.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")
println("Hello World"+f.format(Date()))
```

Comment: Isn't India is GMT+5:30? I think India is IST

Comment: Even IST is not working too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IST or UTC doesn't works for me so, I added Asia/Calcutta timezone.

```
val f = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z")
println("Hello World"+f)
f.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta")
println("Hello World"+f.format(Date()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your 1st `println("Hello World"+f)` prints something like:

```
Hello Worldjava.text.SimpleDateFormat@4d810dfa
```

because you're printing the reference to the object `f`. 
Change it to:

```
println("Hello World"+f.format(Date()))
```

and you will get the current local date/time as it is defined in your pc settings.  
If you want to print date/time for India specifically:

```
f.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST")
println(f.format(Date()))
```

Comment: Still its showing wrong value now, India time is 2:40AM IST 11/18/18 but it shows  Hello World 2018-11-17 21:09:26 GMT+00:00

Comment: At this moment I got: `2018-11-17 21:16:45 GMT` and 
`2018-11-18 02:46:45 IST`

Comment: I am not sure why I am getting wrong value if I use the above code.

Comment: I see there is a difference of 30mins between your GMT and mine. Is there a case that in India there are different time zones?

Comment: I think India follows GMT.

Comment: I meant that since India is a very large country maybe the time zone at the East is different than the time zone at the West.

Comment: I think India follows only one time and not like US have different time zones.

Comment: Yes I've checked that, but it comes with 2 different names for the same time zone: `IST` and `Asia/Kolkata`

Comment: I will go ahead with Asia/Kolkata. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone for your response and Below code works for me.

```
val calender = Calendar.getInstance()

    calender.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta")

    println("Hello World"+
        calender.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY).toString() + ":" + calender.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + calender.getActualMinimum(
            Calendar.SECOND
        )
    )
```